# Error R10 (Boot timeout) > Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

Tags: java, docker, heroku, dockerfile

I'm deploying an Docker image with CMD line in it :

```
CMD ["java","-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions","-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.server.port=$PORT","-Dserver.port=$PORT","-jar","/life-project.jar"]
```

while in the log it looks like :

```
2018-08-06T10:51:17.489612+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command java -XX:\+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:\+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Djava.security.egd\=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.server.port\=\48227 -Dserver.port\=\48227 -jar /life-project.jar
```

with the following error :

```
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106011+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106012+00:00 app[web.1]: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106014+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106015+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106017+00:00 app[web.1]: Description:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106018+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106020+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106021+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106022+00:00 app[web.1]: Property: server.port
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106024+00:00 app[web.1]: Value: $PORT
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106025+00:00 app[web.1]: Origin: "server.port" from property source "systemProperties"
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106026+00:00 app[web.1]: Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106028+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106029+00:00 app[web.1]: Action:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106030+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-08-06T10:51:26.106032+00:00 app[web.1]: Update your application's configuration
```

What should I change in the configuration?

Comment: Check to make sure `"-Dserver.port=$PORT"` is valid

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create the following entry in your `application.properties` (or yaml):

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

The reason is described in the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). You can put `$` vars in the `CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

`-Dserver.port` should be first, like this

```sh
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /opt/application.jar" ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct generally speaking, but depending on the environment, (1) it's possible `PORT` is not defined, and (2) it's possible for the var `PORT` to get lost somewhere in the translation between host > container > JVM. This is especially the case if you use `-Dserver.port` instead of `--server.port`.

For me, what solved this was to default the value in both application.properties and Dockerfile, and to use `--server.port` instead of `-Dserver.port`:

```
// application.properties
server.port=${PORT:8080}
```

```
// Dockerfile
CMD ["java", "-jar", "myapp.jar", "--server.port=${PORT:8080}"]
```